# JavaFX on headless device

Tags: javafx, terminal, raspberry-pi

I have built a javafx program and one part of it is a "server" which I can make print to a console but right now it prints to a text area in the javafx app. I changed the printstream to do this.

One thing I tried was changing the main() method to to check if GraphicsEnvironment.isHandless() was true and if it was I'd run the headless server instead of the javafx app which has a client and server option.

However that gave me an exception saying graphics couldn't be initialised `sew`

Any ideas on how I can successfully run a JavaFX app on a VPS or Raspberry pi for example?

Thanks

Comment: Which method throws this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the best way to do this was modify my Main class to check a headless argument being passed through when running the jar.

Then if it was I'd run a headless version of a class I made and if it wasn't then I'd run the JavaFX application.